# Content Translation installation breaks the website (statistics module error + aliases not taken into account)

Tags: database, i18n-l10n, path-aliases

First, I would like to say I am a total noob in Drupal and PHP but possess some knowledge on other web frameworks/languages).

Here is my path to the errors:

I used the UI to install **Content Translation** and **Configuration Translation** modules from the multilingual core (other 2 modules were already installed).

This did not work properly as it totally broke the website:

- **aliases not respected** (from "/contact" to "/node/3" for instance)
- **an error on statistics module** for some pages (the most important ones of course).

Here is the error on module statistics:

```
Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mytablename.node_counter' doesn't exist: SELECT "nc"."totalcount" AS "totalcount", "nc"."daycount" AS "daycount", "nc"."timestamp" AS "timestamp" FROM {node_counter} "nc" WHERE "nid" IN (:db_condition_placeholder_0); Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 16 ) in statistics_node_links_alter() (line 55 of /srv/mywebsitedomain/drupal/web/core/modules/statistics/statistics.module).
```

("mywebsitedomain" and "mytablename" are dummy names because I cannot share the website name unfortunately.)

To be fair, I do not understand why it happened as I did not dive into the code or anything else.

Did some of you had the same issue, or possess some insight about how to fix it?

I would really appreciate some help.

Thank you !

Comment: Do you try reinstall module statistics. See message error, problem from tabel node_counter does not exit. So you need to reinstall module to add table.

Comment: Thank you I will try it, however I don't want to lose data. In the UI, after selecting uninstall, it warns me that data will be lost. Can't we just reinstall it without totally uninstalling it ?

Comment: I did an uninstall (statistics are secondary at this point I just want the website to work). But now it does not seems be be able to install Statistics anymore. I check it, click on install and then the page refresh but the module is still unchecked.

Comment: Hello, just so you know, I used a backup to revert everything. That's a shame because I did not find how to solve this issue. Thank you for your help